# ! Paragraph ended before \\DeclareNewLayer was complete

Tags: koma-script, scrlayer-scrpage

Sorry for yet another “Paragraph ended before … was complete.”, but I think this one is due to some limitations of `\DeclareNewLayer`.

I'm declaring a layer resp. pagestyle with `scrlayer`, which should contain some text with paragraphs. I'm placing the paragraphs with ps-tricks and I'm putting it into a parbox. But unfortunately I'm getting a `! Paragraph ended before \\DeclareNewLayer was complete.` error at line 11 (the empty line after “First Paragraph”). Is there any way of adding a paragraph within a koma layer?

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{scrlayer}   % KOMA package providing \DeclareNewLayer and \DeclarePageStyleByLayers commands
\usepackage{pstricks}   % PS-Tricks

\DeclareNewLayer[align=tr,page,background,contents={%
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(21,29.7)
    \psset{unit=1mm}
    \rput[lt](10,30){\parbox{100mm}{
    First Paragraph

    Some Text in a new paragraph
    }}
\end{pspicture}
}%
]{example-layer}

\DeclarePageStyleByLayers{example}{example-layer}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{example}
This is some Text
\end{document}
```

Comment: use `\endgraf` instead of a blank line

Comment: `\endgraf` gives me a new line, but it doesn't seam to add the parskip

Comment: \parskip and \parindent are zero by default in parboxes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\endgraf` (which is the `\par` primitive) to avoid the restrictions on the `\par` token.  LaTeX `\parboxes` by default have 0pt indent and 0pt parskip so look rather like a linebreak. If you do not want that you can use

```
\parbox{100mm}{\setlength\parindent{5mm}\setlength\parskip{\baselineskip}% or whatever
    First Paragraph
    \endgraf
    Some Text in a new paragraph
    }}
```